# Commercial SIP VVoIP video call library with H264 support under iOS (Android a plus)

Tags: ios, sip, voip, h.264, video-conferencing

I'm looking for a *commercial* iOS library supporting Video call over SIP, with H264 as video codec. Right now I've only found TeamSpirit SDK. Haven't found if CounterPath has a SDK available.

It has to be

- SIP based.
- Support audio and video calls.
- Support H264 for video, preferrably with a codec included.
- at least basic call support.

PS: No need to mention SaaS like OpenTok or GPL solutions (pjsip/linphone). Already looked into it.

Comment: I'm currently developing a commercial SIP/RTP-based iOS video conferencing library (including hardware-accelerated h.264 encode/decode), however it probably won't be ready for another month or two if you can wait that long. E-mail me james<at>curiousminds.com

Comment: Ramon, were you able to achieve this??? which library you used??

Comment: Not really... the project was abandoned.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if they support H.264 but here are two worth looking:

- [Media5](http://www.media5corp.com/en/developer-solutions/m5t-sce)
- [Radvision](http://www.radvision.com/Products/Developer/VoIP-Developer-Tools/SIP-Developer-Suite/)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend

[IntegrIT Crystal Vu](http://www.integrit.com)